# application can’t connect to shopify server

Tags: shopify

We are developing applications for Shopify and have faced the problem. When trying to install the application via API on the second step of installation our application can’t connect to your server via link:  https://kuvalis-hilll-and-kautzer576.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token. The problem is seen on the screenshot:

http://spur-i-t.com/media/bug.png

Is it possible that our server IP or domain is filtered by your system and all requests are blocked from it?
There is no problem to install from production server of ecommerce-pc.spur-i-t.com but when we try to install from other identical server:  testing.ecommerce-pc.spur-i-t.com with the same PHP settings and available ports, the connection error to your server occurs.
There is no problem with connection to other websites using SSL. It seems that the problem is at your side. Could you please explain what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look in the logs and the POST requests to kuvalis-hilll-and-kautzer576.myshopify.com are completing successfully, can you provide any other logging from the library you are using?

Something to note is the response will be in json format, is it possible that the library you are using is not expecting this?

Also, the screenshot you posted is using a different shop than the link included in this post. Is it working in one case and not the other?

Have you tried the same flow using cURL? Doing so would likely bring the issue to the surface and provide better logging so we can debug what is going on.

No other issues like this have been reported so it is likely an issue with the library you are using.

Comment: Problem occurs when script trying to connect with any Shopify store.
Port 443 to connect via https open on our server. It can be seen in the screenshot
http://spur-i-t.com/media/step3.png
and
http://spur-i-t.com/media/step4.png

which shows that when script is connected with https://encrypted.google.tsom it gets a response

Comment: and when script is connected with shopify store it have got nothing. 

It can be seen in the screenshots
http://spur-i-t.com/media/step1.png
and
http://spur-i-t.com/media/step2.png


If we are trying to use the same script from analogue server with the same php and server settings both variants work.
Difference just in the IP and domain names of servers (configured on amazon AWS cloud):
1st server: testing.ecommerce-pc.spur-i-t.com  (don't work!)
2nd server: ecommerce-pc.spur-i-t.com  (works!)

Comment: John, could you check our problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what to check since you didn't post any of the things I asked for. Simplify what you are doing, use command line cURL to see what is happening, post the raw request and response and I'll have something to look into.